# How can I find the values of each coefficient within a vector in a matrix multiplication problem?

Tags: matrix-equations

I have all the other T and alpha values and I'm trying to solve for a0 a1 and a2 [image]

I can't simply divide them [image]

so I figure in need to do something like this

[image]

But i'm not sure how to go about it?  What's this called?  Do I substitute all the `a, a1, a2` values for one another?  Can someone just tell me what kind of problem this is so I may have better luck googling?  Thank you.

In your link I assume the following would yield the answer:

[image]

but I don't know how to compute what appears to be one matrix divided by another `[Matrix]/[Matrix]`  What's that called?

Regardless following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKZyszzmyeQ) to find `A^-1` and then multiplying that by B like in this [other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRdVU8tyRDU) will give me what I want yes? ( `a0, a1, a2` )

Answer (score 1):

On your $A\cdot X=B$ problem, if you know the matrix $A$ and the right vector $B$,  then the solution is simply $X = A^{-1}\cdot B$. Or did I missed something ?

Or if you really want to play manually with the system of equations, there is the classical  [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) trick, combining lines togethers to create zeros in the matrix, up to the point it becomes trivial to solve (triangular, or even diagonal).

Comment: How do i find A^-1 ?

Comment: Is that really all I have to do?  `X = A^-1 * B` ?

Comment: Yes. ( $A^-1$ is the inverse of the 3x3 matrix ). For matrix inversion formulas, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems

Comment: Thank you for your help, and sorry to be so annoying, but I just want to make sure I get this correct.  If you can validate what I added above, the green mark is yours.  Thank you.

Comment: these are not matrices, these are determinants. click the link just above (2D case) to see how to compute them.   (In which class level are you ? The problem you want to solve seems a lot more advance than the level where system solving and determinants are usually tauch :-) ).